# Django to call the correct function

Tags: python, html, django

been searching a lot for fixing my issue.. New to django and might be missing a very simple logic here and looking for some help..

I have created a form in html page called **thispage.html** as below:

```
<form action="{% url 'getvaluefromform' %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name='mytitle' placeholder="enter title">
<input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

then I updated **views.py** with the below code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request,'thispage.html')

def getvaluefromform(request):
    mytitle = request.POST.get('mytitle')
    print(mytitle)
    return render(request,'thispage.html')
```

finally my **urls.py** has this part:

```
from dhango.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('',views.index,name='index'),
path('getvaluefromform',views.getvaluefromform,name='getvaluefromform')
]
```

**Problem**:
when I use this I am able to get the input vallue however the url is changing to '/getvaluefromform' and when I remove 'getvaluefromform' from the url section and just keep it '' then the code view index gets picked up.

Is there a way I can call the second function when button is clicked without moving to the new path. Please advise.

P.S - I am deliberately not using a model form because I want to build a raw sql query based on user input and then run the query to get the results/ create a new table on the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Django forms:**

If you want to get POST data from a form without changing routes you have a very good [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#the-view) in the official documentation.

**HTML forms:**

If you're not into Django forms you can do as stated below.

```
def getvaluefromform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        mytitle = request.POST.get('mytitle')
        return render(request,'otherpage.html')
    return render(request,'thispage.html')
```

What this will do is basically check if there's a POST request, get the form data and if there's a GET request, you'll just render the defined page.

If you must have two different routes, I suggest using Javascript.

Comment: Hi Lucas, Isn't this using the django form? I am trying to do it without a django form.. Sorry.. I might been misinterpreting your answer here..

Comment: @KarthikViz added a HTML form case to the answer. Try it there! :D